# json api call error, what am I doing wrong

Tags: php, json, api

I made an api call successfully but am getting errors after indexing it

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://app.morenaija.ng/@api/search/YouTube/'.$search_term.'');
$yt_data = json_decode($json);

?>
```

below is the output response

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "CevxZvSJLk8",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Roar (Official)",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CevxZvSJLk8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLDY5ZX7PoN7KNzXXEdQ_Yvch8qqQQ",
            "channelTitle": "Katy Perry",
            "channelId": "UCYvmuw-JtVrTZQ-7Y4kd63Q",
            "publishedAt": "6 years ago",
            "duration": "4:30",
            "viewCount": "3068657449"
        },
        {
            "id": "UW5SMrURVbM",
            "title": "Roar - Katy Perry (Lyrics) ??",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UW5SMrURVbM/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLBFmmujndykkc75SeCIl05VPHaglw",
            "channelTitle": "DopeLyrics",
            "channelId": "UCvR2R7j218tzejtTsb_X6Rw",
            "publishedAt": "1 year ago",
            "duration": "3:51",
            "viewCount": "14073787"
        },
        {
            "id": "FqkfBzRb43o",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Roar : Part 2 (Official Cover by 10 year-old Mariangeli from HitStreak)",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FqkfBzRb43o/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLBnXgcoefqzxawvmhB-QbCvMUBENg",
            "channelTitle": "ShowMobile",
            "channelId": "UCYBFx-THKRWqAxq66qZk_ww",
            "publishedAt": "6 years ago",
            "duration": "3:47",
            "viewCount": "307490768"
        },
        {
            "id": "Rh47oTsRf-w",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Roar (From “The Prismatic World Tour Live”)",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Rh47oTsRf-w/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLAsKxSyujUT_ZCQqsAdpVQAGnxP3Q",
            "channelTitle": "Katy Perry",
            "channelId": "UCYvmuw-JtVrTZQ-7Y4kd63Q",
            "publishedAt": "4 years ago",
            "duration": "4:33",
            "viewCount": "21381621"
        },
        {
            "id": "KRlhDkwJkHU",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Roar (OFFICIAL 1 Hour)",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KRlhDkwJkHU/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLCOvC3IMGpgbitf9nn58BxMFpqJnw",
            "channelTitle": "SONGS 1 HOUR",
            "channelId": "UCEo7MW5ArVEzQCQRpTuNGDg",
            "publishedAt": "4 years ago",
            "duration": "1:01:11",
            "viewCount": "27253"
        },
        {
            "id": "empcJOD-bA0",
            "title": "Roar by Katy Perry Lyrics",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/empcJOD-bA0/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLBcizW9oc4KLGEo5o3Z2kOmKbKOkQ",
            "channelTitle": "mulero ibrahim",
            "channelId": "UCEl6sNUx9xHQ8zyypGJnlWQ",
            "publishedAt": "4 years ago",
            "duration": "3:45",
            "viewCount": "423025"
        },
        {
            "id": "K-w2sYAqMKw",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Roar (One Love Manchester)",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/K-w2sYAqMKw/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLDjF35LoaRotGJ8WvhB4Nc9oZPvqQ",
            "channelTitle": "BBC Music",
            "channelId": "UCZtDUmC3W7j25XHZWFT_XgQ",
            "publishedAt": "2 years ago",
            "duration": "3:50",
            "viewCount": "12996443"
        },
        {
            "id": "sLZvdAdlQq4",
            "title": "Play Doh ROAR - Katy Perry Barbie Doll Inspired Costume",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sLZvdAdlQq4/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLA-i8iXAj-galqb2-0P1w82JdDXcQ",
            "channelTitle": "Fondanista",
            "channelId": "UCVNrpO7KiVMdwOdFZwLkWRA",
            "publishedAt": "4 years ago",
            "duration": "2:58",
            "viewCount": "14677198"
        },
        {
            "id": "0KSOMA3QBU0",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Dark Horse (Official) ft. Juicy J",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0KSOMA3QBU0/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLDa1ue7JhfY14YUSCsVhgf7o2kWyw",
            "channelTitle": "Katy Perry",
            "channelId": "UCYvmuw-JtVrTZQ-7Y4kd63Q",
            "publishedAt": "6 years ago",
            "duration": "3:45",
            "viewCount": "2773465353"
        },
        {
            "id": "Z0Q8j3HJagE",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Making of the \"Roar\" Music Video",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Z0Q8j3HJagE/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLAj6fVgZFc8eblIa5hC6CwvxasbNQ",
            "channelTitle": "Katy Perry",
            "channelId": "UCYvmuw-JtVrTZQ-7Y4kd63Q",
            "publishedAt": "6 years ago",
            "duration": "22:31",
            "viewCount": "20739183"
        },
        {
            "id": "EyLCXC3rV2M",
            "title": "**LYRICS** Katy Perry - Roar",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EyLCXC3rV2M/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLBGnc2_UQBdmVbEvfzHuZf6GVldlQ",
            "channelTitle": "ilpescepalla",
            "channelId": "UCTnd7uvo-uWwlB9qvh0aucA",
            "publishedAt": "6 years ago",
            "duration": "4:04",
            "viewCount": "2940062"
        },
        {
            "id": "pQQ24JwtRUI",
            "title": "Olivia Sings Roar | The Voice Kids Australia 2014",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pQQ24JwtRUI/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLCKE6eUp7Iye7_Wx8_0YOOPwpWamw",
            "channelTitle": "The Voice Kids Australia",
            "channelId": "UCUDR5r3ow3goI1iZgGlnoyw",
            "publishedAt": "5 years ago",
            "duration": "4:28",
            "viewCount": "95223791"
        },
        {
            "id": "aqhCJW890So",
            "title": "Mariangeli from HitStreak - ROAR : Part 1",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aqhCJW890So/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLCj4EwhFnnFVcjJtF_3hUBYQ83WZw",
            "channelTitle": "ShowMobile",
            "channelId": "UCYBFx-THKRWqAxq66qZk_ww",
            "publishedAt": "6 years ago",
            "duration": "0:33",
            "viewCount": "32701801"
        },
        {
            "id": "KlyXNRrsk4A",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Last Friday Night (T.G.I.F.)",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KlyXNRrsk4A/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLAR2QvImCYQhf_dP5WFJiWVKU00fw",
            "channelTitle": "Katy Perry",
            "channelId": "UCYvmuw-JtVrTZQ-7Y4kd63Q",
            "publishedAt": "8 years ago",
            "duration": "8:11",
            "viewCount": "1239885938"
        },
        {
            "id": "UUT2GTujJI0",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Roar Lyrics",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UUT2GTujJI0/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLDUKvQC8DQIg7dD39mEjDetWdHMsA",
            "channelTitle": "K- Hype",
            "channelId": "UCcoS9-5e2PPrO5gIqC9Fy4Q",
            "publishedAt": "6 years ago",
            "duration": "3:45",
            "viewCount": "90138"
        },
        {
            "id": "QGJuMBdaqIw",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Firework (Official)",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QGJuMBdaqIw/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLCVFJ6nMr1OyDp5P9wNafG76miRoA",
            "channelTitle": "Katy Perry",
            "channelId": "UCYvmuw-JtVrTZQ-7Y4kd63Q",
            "publishedAt": "9 years ago",
            "duration": "3:54",
            "viewCount": "1233775759"
        },
        {
            "id": "ZKmuyy6xEBU",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Firework, Roar & Never Really Over LIVE - SHEIN Together",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZKmuyy6xEBU/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLAqsqPbUkw6GHnIB_my6JIuS9ondA",
            "channelTitle": "KPEZ",
            "channelId": "UCv1DBOB5sc6vrjYEkwNsHcw",
            "publishedAt": "1 day ago",
            "duration": "11:52",
            "viewCount": "2688"
        },
        {
            "id": "qvBzVWdwZFg",
            "title": "Katy Perry - Roar (Live @ BBC Radio 1's Big Weekend)",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qvBzVWdwZFg/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLDujpTCwyTAWK3t-MozoxcjvBhtjw",
            "channelTitle": "HeyHey Hey",
            "channelId": "UCMYxD0p4_-GxQ1qYYDsK-FQ",
            "publishedAt": "3 years ago",
            "duration": "4:38",
            "viewCount": "98831"
        },
        {
            "id": "Sl8Wl4EFBGQ",
            "title": "KATY PERRY WITH ZERO BUDGET! (Roar PARODY)",
            "thumbDefault": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Sl8Wl4EFBGQ/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLCybyCTPmI82feN8Rzcmu_0ERrVpA",
            "channelTitle": "LankyBox",
            "channelId": "UCSf0s2ogUVYpJPuzW1zpAOg",
            "publishedAt": "6 months ago",
            "duration": "1:24",
            "viewCount": "2759481"
        }
    ]
}
```

below is how I get the things I want for this call

```
<?php echo $yt_data->items[0]->title; ?>
<?php echo $yt_data->items[0]->channelTitle; ?>
e.t.c
```

**error_log**
[20-Jan-2023 09:34:50 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: title in /home/patch/aheadv.com/search_main.php on line 11
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: yt_data in /home/patch/aheadv.com/search_main.php on line 81
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'items' of non-object in /home/patch/aheadv.com/search_main.php on line 81
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'title' of non-object in /home/patch/aheadv.com/search_main.php on line 81
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: yt_data in /home/patch/aheadv.com/search_main.php on line 82
e.tc

Ho do I solve the error issues

```
<?php
require_once('admin/config.php');
require_once('includes/url_slug.php'); 
if(isset($_GET['change'])){ header("Location: ".$site_url."/".cano($_GET['q'])); }
$search_term = urlencode($_GET['q']);
$save_search = cano($_GET['q']);
$search_title = str_replace("Audio", " ", $save_search);
$search_title = ucwords($search_title);
$yt_id = $_GET["q"];
$url = 'https://app.morenaija.ng/@api/search/YouTube/'.$search_term;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($json === false) {
    echo "Error: ".curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $yt_data = json_decode($json);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        echo "Error: ".json_last_error_msg();
    } else {
        if(isset($yt_data->items[0]->title)){
            $first_item_title = $yt_data->items[0]->title;
            echo $first_item_title;
        }
        if(isset($yt_data->items[0]->channelId)){
            $first_item_channelId = $yt_data->items[0]->channelId;
            echo $first_item_channelId;
        }
    }
}
?>

    <title><?php echo $yt_data->items[0]->title; ?> Mp4 mp3 Download - <?php echo $site_title;?></title>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, getting `Katy Perry - Roar (Official)` and `Katy Perry` with your data

Comment: @brombeer do you want to call the api?

Comment: I don't _want to_, no. Should I call the api? You said you made a successful call to the API and posted its data. Accessing that data the way you did doesn't trigger a notice, it returns the value. _If_ you have other api calls that return a different or no result you should check if those fields actually exist in your data before trying to output them